# gorm one to many search

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Have the following problem: 
I have Bookmaker and Users domain classes. And one Bookmaker has many Users.

```
class Bookmaker {
    ...
    static hasMany = [users: User ...]
    ...
}
```

And User domain class doesn't contain reference to Bookmaker.
My goal is to create method that will return Bookmaker that owns particular User.
It looks like:

```
def lookupBookmaker() {
    User user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
    def query = Bookmaker.where {
        users.contains(user)
    }
    Bookmaker bookmaker = query.find()
    bookmaker
}
```

but it doesn't work and gives the following exception:

> Class groovy.lang.MissingMethodException Message No signature of
>   method: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.contains() is applicable for
>   argument types: (cmscore.User) values: [cmscore.User : 2] Possible
>   solutions: toString(), toString(), notify(), combinations()

and it says that wrong code is this:

> users.contains(user)

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `Bookmaker.where { users { id == user.id } }`? or just use `springSecurityService.principal.id` instead of fetching the User initially.